# Passing unmanaged to managed int pointer

Tags: c#, interop

I have a DLL, which I cannot change but was written in C++. It is calling a function in my managed C# DLL (which I am free to change). There are a lot of parameters which need to be passed but some work and some dont.

There is no problem passing along an "unsigned char*", but there is a problem passing an "unsigned int**" or an "int*".

When the C++ DLL sends an int* I try to catch it in my C# DLL with a "uint*". I get a compiler error saying cannot convert parameter from "int*" to "long*".

I have tried all sorts of UInt16, ushort etc, but I always get similar errors.

How do I marshal this pointer array into my program?

Comment: How do you call a managed DLL from native code? Do you use COM interop?

Answer (score 1):

did you try with IntPtr ? I believe it can be used for Handles and also for pointers to integers.

Comment: Yes. When I catch the int* with a IntPtr the error is "cannot convert parameter from int* to long

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Davide on the IntPtr.   You need to have the parameter read as an IntPtr.  After the Interop is complete you can then do a MyIntPtr.ToInt32() or whatever conversion you might like.